# Get connection used by DatabaseFactory.GetDatabase().ExecuteReader()

Tags: enterprise-library, asp.net-3.5, transactionscope

We have two different query strategies that we'd ideally like to operate in conjunction on our site without opening redundant connections. One strategy uses the enterprise library to pull `Database` objects and `Execute_____(DbCommand)`s on the `Database`, without directly selecting any sort of connection. Effectively like this:

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand q = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SomeProc");
using (IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader(q))
{
  List<RecordType> rv = new List<RecordType>();
  while (r.Read())
  {
    rv.Add(RecordType.CreateFromReader(r));
  }
  return rv;
}
```

The other, newer strategy, uses a library that asks for an `IDbConnection`, which it `Close()`es immediately after execution. So, we do something like this:

```
DbConnection c = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase().CreateConnection();
using (QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder(c))
{
  return qb.Find<RecordType>(ConditionCollection);
}
```

But, the connection returned by `CreateConnection()` isn't the same one used by the `Database.ExecuteReader()`, which is apparently left open between queries. So, when we call a data access method using the *new* strategy after one using the *old* strategy inside a `TransactionScope`, it causes unnecessary promotion -- promotion that I'm not sure we have the ability to configure for (we don't have administrative access to the SQL Server).

Before we go down the path of modifying the query-builder-library to work with the Enterprise Library's `Database` objects ... **Is there a way to retrieve, if existent, the open connection last used by one of the `Database.Execute_______()` methods?**

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008 R2 (10.50.1600.1) in our development environment. 2008 (10.0.1600.22) in production. (We don't own the production server.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get the connection associated with a transaction.  Enterprise Library internally manages a collection of transactions and the associated database connections so if you are in a transaction you can retrieve the connection associated with a database using the static `TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnection` method:

```cs
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    IEnumerable<RecordType> records = GetRecordTypes();

    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    DbConnection connection = TransactionScopeConnections.GetConnection(db).Connection;
}

public static IEnumerable<RecordType> GetRecordTypes()
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    DbCommand q = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetLogEntries");
    using (IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader(q))
    {
        List<RecordType> rv = new List<RecordType>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            rv.Add(RecordType.CreateFromReader(r));
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```